# "The mean value of π will be found to be 40.000000"

Tags: math-history

Reading something by lewis Carrol on the value of π and he states

"In the early treatises on this subject, the mean value assigned to π will be found to be 40.000000. Later writers suspected that the decimeal point had been accidentally shifted and that the proper value was 400.0000: but as the details of the process for obtaining it had been lost, now further progress was made in the subject until our own time."

Has anyone got any details on this? what do they mean by the 'mean value of π'. I need some assistance in understanding this

[source](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_New_Method_of_Evaluation_as_Applied_to_Pi_(unsourced))

[edit]

Ok its fine, I just cant read

" humorous exposition on how the Greek professor and controversial Biblical scholar Benjamin Jowett (here "J") might have come to receive the insulting salary of £40 a year, which was eventually increased to £500 after it was discovered that such a low salary was in fact a breach of contract."

Comment: Maybe he's making a joke....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Very likely because the first line of the source reads „ A humorous exposition on how the Greek professor and controversial Biblical scholar Benjamin Jowett (here "J") might have come to receive the insulting salary of £40 a year, which was eventually increased to £500 after it was discovered that such a low salary was in fact a breach of contract.“

Comment: Finally the proper value fixed as $42$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown wow ... I completely missed that fml

Comment: "The geometry we're using for this run is a modified Minkowski space that we can derive by setting pi to four; there's no fractal dimension involved, but things are complicated slightly because the space to which we're mapping this diagram has a luminiferous aether. Gather round, please, you need to be inside the security cordon when I power up the circuit. Manesh, if you could switch on the ABSOLUTELY NO ENTRY sign ..." Charles Stross, *The Atrocity Archives*.

Comment: See [Lewis Carroll: A Biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=a-8NBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT227) regarding [Benjamin Jowett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Jowett#Oxford_career).